# Check if Symbol is negative in sympy

Tags: sympy

In sympy you can check if a number is negative using the `is_negative` attribute, however this returns `None` for a Symbol. I want to be able to check whether a Symbol is preceded by a minus sign or not. I can do this with:

```py
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol("-G")

if str(x)[0] == "-":
    print("Value is preceded by a minus sign")
```

but is there a better way than just looking at the string representation of the Symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is a symbol "name" that has a leading negative in it. You can check for such a leading negative sign with `x.name.startswith("-")`. It is more common, however, to test semantically whether an expression/symbol has a negative coefficient. That can be done as follows:

```
>>> from sympy.core.function import _coeff_isneg as f
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> f(-x)
True
```

Note that `x` here has the name "x" and the minus sign reresents a factor of -1 in the expression `-x`.

Comment: Note that this function is just looking for a literal negative sign on the leading factor; it is not indicating whether the leading number is negative, e.g. `f((1 - pi)*x) -> False` whereas `((1-pi)*x).coeff(x).is_negative -> True`